# To Get Diagonals of a Matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I want to get diagonals from a matrix in Matlab.
For example, given the following matrix

```
M = [1  1   4   5   4
     2  5   1   2   2
     4  1   2   1   3
     1  3   1   1   1
     1  2   3   3   1]
```

I want to get a list of vectors which make the upper diagonals:
`{[1 1 1 1], [4 2 3], [5 2] [4]}`.

### One attempt

I want to replace if-clauses by a while-loop in Matlab

```
     if (i==j)
        A(t+1,i) = M(i,j)
     end
     if (i==j+1) 
        A(t+1,i) = M(i,j)
     end
     ...
     if (i==j+N) 
        A(t+1,i) = M(i,j)
     end
```

To store all diagonals of the matrix

```
t = 0;
while (t < 5)   % if-clauses replaced here by this
   for i=1:5
      for j=i:5
          if (i == j+t)
             trend(t+1,i) = M(i,j); 
          end
      end
   end
t = t + 1;
end
```

The idea is to store elements into the matrix `trend` with the condition `i == j+t` that is a condition I find holds for the diagonals of the upper triangle. 
The if-clauses are replaced by false pseudocode, which tries to go through the upper triangle of the matrix, but false because no "1" vector found in `trend`

---

How can you get diagonals from a matrix in Matlab?

Comment: What is your question again? I'm sorry but despite the length and two blocks of code, I don't understand at all.

Comment: I get the strong feeling you're trying to reinvent the wheel here but I have no idea because it's not clear at all what you're trying to do and your sample does not function.

Comment: too many loops.. For instance, you can create an off-diagonal matrix like this `diag(ones(1,99), 1)`. Also the if-statements if the marked section are overwriting the same location in `A`.. Also what is `t`?

Comment: Please make sure the first code is actually correct and running before continuing: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Matlab is short for matrix laboratory. Since matricies are already basic building blocks there are simple methods to read/write them, like mentioned before: diag() reads or writes the diagonal and can even be used on off-diagonal entries. Others are zeros(), ones(), rand(), magic(),....

Comment: Adding some sample input and output matrices would make this a lot easier to understand. but make them *5*-by-*5* rather than *100*-by-*100*

Comment: "To store all diagonals of the matrix" what does this mean? Are you trying to recreate the `triu` function? As in `triu(M)`?

Comment: Since you used random input, you need to include the sample input that matches that output. Better would be to not use a random input but something more predictable like `reshape(1:25,5,5)`

Comment: @Masi can you also show the expected output for that sample 5x5 matrix you posted?

Comment: I see, this can be easily done with the `spdiags` function

Comment: @Masi you could have eliminated a whole lot of confusion from this question if you'd just written `M = [...]` instead of that first nested loop which actually has nothing to do with your question what so ever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to use the `spdiags` function to extract the upper off-diagonals. Example:

```
N = 5;
M = magic(N)
D = spdiags(M, 1:N-1)
DD = arrayfun(@(i) D(i+1:end,i).', 1:N-1, 'Uniform',false)
celldisp(DD)
```

The result:

```
M =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9

D =
     0     0     0     0
    24     0     0     0
     7     1     0     0
    20    14     8     0
     3    22    16    15

DD = 
    [1x4 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x2 double]    [15]
DD{1} =
    24     7    20     3
DD{2} =
     1    14    22
DD{3} =
     8    16
DD{4} =
    15
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it generalises the situation well.

Comment: Thanks. The issue here was the way you described your problem was very confusing.. In the future, always consider adding a small example of the input and the expected output you're looking for, along with how you tried to solve it. But it's important to include examples...

Answer (score 2):

try to replace this part:

```
         if (i==j)
            A(t+1,i) = M(i,j)
         end
         if (i==j+1) 
            A(t+1,i) = M(i,j)
         end
         ...
         if (i==j+N) 
            A(t+1,i) = M(i,j)
         end
```

with:

```
             if (i>=j && i<=j+N) 
                A(t+1,i) = M(i,j)
             end
```

Comment: Wrong output. See the body.

Comment: Well, I have posted this answer to one of the earliest version of he question. Which in itself is a correct substitution. Bu now I see that the question has evolved to a much more different one...

Comment: I am sorry about confusion. I tested it with older version of the question. You can try it yourself. I cannot get the expected output. I may be also wrong too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want a while loop. What about directly indexing each of your diagonals using MATLAB's built-in [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) function:

```
n = size(M,1)
for t = 1:n-1
    trend{t} = M(diag(true(n-t,1),t));    
end
```

Comment: Correct output here! Format is like a row of columns in a cell.